# get() on OptionMenu -> tkinter Python 3

Tags: python, tkinter, get, optionmenu

How can i get the 'get()' to get the value at the moment of the click on the Button?
The value printed always stays the one i've set by default...

```
    langues = ['FR', 'EN']
    nb_joueurs = [2, 3, 4]

    var_langues = StringVar()
    var_nb_joueurs = IntVar()
    var_langues.set(langues[0])
    var_nb_joueurs.set(nb_joueurs[0])


    Label(self.frame_droit, text='Choix de la langue:').pack()
    OptionMenu(self.frame_droit, var_langues, *langues).pack(expand=True)
    Label(self.frame_droit, text='Nombre de joueurs:').pack()
    OptionMenu(self.frame_droit, var_nb_joueurs, *nb_joueurs).pack(expand=True)
    Button(self.frame_droit, text="NOUVELLE PARTIE", bg='#1394ab', fg='white', height=2,
                             width=20, ***command=lambda:print(f'{choix_langue} and {choix_nb_joueurs}')).pack()
    choix_nb_joueurs=var_nb_joueurs.get()
    choix_langue=var_langues.get()***
```

Answer (score 0):

Have the button call a function. Assuming that your widgets are global variables, you can call get like you would at any other time.

```
def do_something():
    choix_langue = var_langues.get()
    choix_nb_joueurs = var_nb.joueurs.get()
    print(f'{choix_langue} and {choix_nb_joueurs}')

Button(self.frame_droit, ..., command=do_something)
```

For a well-defined program, the use of `lambda` usually makes the code more complex than it needs to be. Functions are easier to read, easier to write, and easier to debug.

Comment: Actually the issue was that i was calling useless variables instead of having the 'get' directly in the button. Variables were set before the click. 

But thanks for your advises!